# String to Date in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, date

Hi I have this code in RoR to convert String into a date:

```
r.valid_from = Date.strptime(row[5], @time_format)
```

row[5] is 7-11-12 and time_format is "%d-%m-%y". The result I get with this code is: November 07, 2012 but I would like to get it in this way: 07 November, 2012. How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're successfully parse the string to the `Date`. So you just need to print your new date in another format.

To achieve `07 November, 2012` result, you can use `strftime`:

```
your_date.strftime('%d %B %Y')
```

Comment: Thanks! But I don't know why is not working in my case.. I have r.valid_from = Date.strptime(row[5], @time_format).strftime("%d %B, %Y") but I get the same result

Comment: You should modify your date during output, not during saving. For example in your `view` file.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to format the time:

```
DateTime.strptime(row[5], @time_format).strftime("%d %B, %Y")
```

See the [documentation on strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime) for all the formatting directives.